# Can't make huge header background image to include navigation part in boostrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am following tutorial from udemy - PSD to Bootstrap 3 for Beginners using HTML & CSS. Followed exact step by step code but in his video the big header image includes the navigation part. but on my code it does not. Here is the PSD I am converting [PSD to be converted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddpIv.jpg)

here is the code:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/uckznd5h9rxf1m2/myProject.zip?dl=0

Please help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS:

```
#slider {
    background: url('../img/bg.jpg');
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background-size: cover;
    top: 0;
}
.navbar-default {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: transparent;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you it works, But now the problem is the logo and menu items are unclickable?

Answer (score 0):

Simply override this class

```
.navbar-default {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index:100;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you it works, But now the problem is the logo and menu items are unclickable?

Comment: Your welcome and I have edited my answer for you, works fine now.